# Problem getting method from MainActivity with context function in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, database, oop

i have this code in my MainActivity() that use to count total records and read it.

```
public void countRecords() {
    int recordCount = new TableControllerStudent(this).count();

    TextView textViewRecordCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRecordCount);
    textViewRecordCount.setText(recordCount + " records found.");

}

public void readRecords() {

    LinearLayout linearLayoutRecords = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutRecords);
    linearLayoutRecords.removeAllViews();

    List<ObjectStudent> students = new TableControllerStudent(this).read();

    if (students.size() > 0) {

        for (ObjectStudent obj : students) {

            int id = obj.id;
            String studentFirstname = obj.firstname;
            String studentEmail = obj.email;

            String textViewContents = studentFirstname + " - " + studentEmail;

            TextView textViewStudentItem= new TextView(this);
            textViewStudentItem.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
            textViewStudentItem.setText(textViewContents);
            textViewStudentItem.setTag(Integer.toString(id));

            linearLayoutRecords.addView(textViewStudentItem);
        }

    }

    else {

        TextView locationItem = new TextView(this);
        locationItem.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        locationItem.setText("No records yet.");

        linearLayoutRecords.addView(locationItem);
    }
}
```

and in the Activity OnListenerCreateStudent it's doesn't work and getting error with this code.

```
    package com.example.coba_crud_db_1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;

public class OnClickListenerCreateStudent implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final Context context = view.getRootView().getContext();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View formElementsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_input_form, null, false);

        final EditText editTextStudentFirstname = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentFirstname);
        final EditText editTextStudentEmail = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentEmail);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(formElementsView)
                .setTitle("Create Student")
                .setPositiveButton("Add",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                String studentFirstname = editTextStudentFirstname.getText().toString();
                                String studentEmail = editTextStudentEmail.getText().toString();

                                ObjectStudent objectStudent = new ObjectStudent();
                                objectStudent.firstname= studentFirstname;
                                objectStudent.email= studentEmail;

                                boolean createSuccessful = new TableControllerStudent(context).create(objectStudent);

                                if(createSuccessful){
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Student information was saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to save student information.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                ((MainActivity)context).countRecords();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }).show();
    }
}
```

Error log :

```
2020-01-31 11:39:18.357 12917-12917/com.example.coba_crud_db_1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.coba_crud_db_1, PID: 12917
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.internal.policy.DecorContext cannot be cast to com.example.coba_crud_db_1.MainActivity
    at com.example.coba_crud_db_1.OnClickListenerCreateStudent$1.onClick(OnClickListenerCreateStudent.java:46)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
    2020-01-31 11:39:18.417 12917-12917/com.example.coba_crud_db_1 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 
    12917 SIG: 9
```

the problem is in the ((MainActivity)context).countRecords(); and ((MainActivity)context).readRecords(); i guess.
i tried different code but it's doesn't work, it's getting force close if im add new records.

Comment: Can you add complete code of  OnListenerCreateStudent definition and also from where you are calling OnListenerCreateStudent

Comment: Avoid using "this" as a context to create widgets and instead use getActivityContext() to avoid memory leaks. The same goes to using "(MainActivity)context", use getApplicationContext() instead. This way you should avoid creating and holding useless references and bad context usages.

Comment: i have already edited it to full code @SurajVaishnav

Comment: from where you instantiated OnClickListenerCreateStudent? I didn't find `new OnClickListenerCreateStudent()`

Comment: @Rildira check my answer and let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the code from where you are showing alert dialo? Also, it is not a good practice to cast context to activity. When you would have a large codebase and same dialog would be used multiple times, it would be a problem. It is better to create an interface and pass to alertdialog and use the callback of interface in your activities/fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If your Alert Dialog method in Main activity, try this.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setView(formElementsView)
            .setTitle("Create Student")
            .setPositiveButton("Add",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        getApplicationContext()
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            String studentFirstname = editTextStudentFirstname.getText().toString();
                            String studentEmail = editTextStudentEmail.getText().toString();

                            ObjectStudent objectStudent = new ObjectStudent();
                            objectStudent.firstname= studentFirstname;
                            objectStudent.email= studentEmail;

                            boolean createSuccessful = new TableControllerStudent(context).create(objectStudent);

                            if(createSuccessful){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Student information was saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to save student information.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            ((MainActivity)context).countRecords();
                            ((MainActivity)context).readRecords();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor inside `OnClickListenerCreateStudent` and pass the activity's reference to the constructor, like:

```
public class OnClickListenerCreateStudent implements View.OnClickListener {

    MainActivity activity;

    public OnClickListenerCreateStudent(MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.activity=activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      //  final Context context = view.getRootView().getContext();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View formElementsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_input_form, null, false);

        final EditText editTextStudentFirstname = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentFirstname);
        final EditText editTextStudentEmail = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentEmail);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setView(formElementsView)
                .setTitle("Create Student")
                .setPositiveButton("Add",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                String studentFirstname = editTextStudentFirstname.getText().toString();
                                String studentEmail = editTextStudentEmail.getText().toString();

                                ObjectStudent objectStudent = new ObjectStudent();
                                objectStudent.firstname= studentFirstname;
                                objectStudent.email= studentEmail;

                                boolean createSuccessful = new TableControllerStudent(context).create(objectStudent);

                                if(createSuccessful){
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Student information was saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to save student information.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                ((MainActivity)context).countRecords();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }).show();
    }
}
```

I don't where you had set `OnClickListenerCreateStudent` but call this:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenerCreateStudent(mainActivityReference));
```